# Localstack limit services used (and thus hopefully go easier on memory)

Tags: web-development-server, localstack

I'm developing a complex web application, using [localstack](https://github.com/atlassian/localstack/blob/master/README.md) to act as the aws analog for me locally.  However, the memory usage is somewhat higher than I want to support, at 770MB.  How can I reduce the services to just what I need, or otherwise reduce the memory footprint of localstack?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the memory footprint by customizing the `SERVICES` configuration variable.

For this, you need to have a Comma-separated list of AWS CLI service names or shorthands to start. Per default, all services are loaded and started on the first request for that service.